# unauthorised calling translate cognitive Service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to upgrade my traduction API calling translate cognitive to V3.0.
First thing I try is calling the api using Insomina software but I always have unauthorized responce.

I used this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference

[image]

In the header, I m adding the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key with the key readable in the azure portal.

[image]

The strange point is that the endpoint given in the doc is: api-eur.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com and the one in the portal is https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/

Am I missing something?
Thank you

Comment: post your endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing the **`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`** directly with the request. Instead

(i)You should obtain the token by passing the url with postman as follows,

[image]

then you need to pass the token with the request as follows,

[image]

Comment: I am not at the moment trying to call texto to speech service but translate service

Comment: I created a cognitive service in my azure portal, the token is from the key pannel in the ressoure. The strange point is that the endpoint given in the doc is: api-eur.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com and the one in the portal is https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/

Comment: No you should create a token with the key and then pass the token to trasnlator api as explained above